# I need to fetch the date from one field "from date" and increement 19 days and pass it into "to-date" in Robot framework.Is thr any other way to do it

Tags: python-3.x, robotframework

How to fetch date and increment the date and pass into the other field in robot framework. I have tried the below code and didn't work.

```
from datetime import datetime, time delta

x = '2017-05-15'
res = (datetime.strptime(x, '%Y-%m-%d') + time delta(days=1)).strftime('%Y-%m-%d')

print(res)    
# 2017-05-16
```

Comment: `time delta
                                        ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax`

Comment: What does "didn't work" mean? Do you get an error? Did it return the incorrect time? Something different?

Comment: import datetime
import timedelta



date= '2017-05-15'
res = (datetime.datetime.strptime(date, '%Y-%m-%d') + timedelta(days=1)).strftime('%Y-%m-%d')

print(res)



getting the below error, do i need to import any other modules?
TypeError: 'module' object is not callable

Comment: Timedelta is inside datetime, you can remove `import timedelta` and use it with `datetime.timedelta`